# Make UIWebview's font bold in iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

How can i make the font to bold

```
[cell.itemContentWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='font-family:-apple-system','HelveticaNeue-Bold; style='font-size:24px;'>%@",object.title] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: This is an HTML question, not an iOS/Objective-C question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafay for your question

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   //Font size
   int fontSize = 80;
   NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", fontSize];
  [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
  //Font Family Style - Bold
   NSString *jsWebViewFontFamilyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = 'HelveticaNeue-Bold'"];
  [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsWebViewFontFamilyString];
  //Font Color or web view text color
  [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'Green'"]; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. Now how can i add  custom color to it.

Comment: I updated my answer please check it.Kindly up vote my answer.It is very helpful for others.

Comment: curiously, changing fontsize is not working anymore with iOS 10.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Just prefix a  tag to your string before loading into the webView.

```
NSString *body = [plist objectForKey:@"foo"];
NSString *htmlString = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<font face='GothamRounded-Bold' size='3'>%@", body];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: `<font>` tag is deprecated for years, long before 2015.